# What is wrong with my argument? (Differentiation of composite function)

Tags: calculus, fake-proofs

The following is from "Calculus 4th Edition" by Michael Spivak.

> THEOREM 9(THE CHAIN RULE)
> If $g$ is differentiable at $a$, and $f$ is differentiable at $g(a)$, then $f\circ g$ is differentiable at $a$, and $$(f\circ g)^{'}(a)=f^{'}(g(a))\cdot g^{'}(a).$$

My wrong argument is here:

Assume that $g$ be differentiable at $a$.
Assume that $f$ be differentiable at $g(a)$.
We consider the case in which $f^{'}(g(a))\cdot g^{'}(a)\neq 0$.
We assume that for any positive real number $\epsilon$, there exists $h$ such that $-\epsilon<h<\epsilon$ and $g(a+h)-g(a)=0$.
The following equation holds when $g(a+h)-g(a)\neq 0$.
$$\frac{f(g(a+h))-f(g(a))}{h}=\frac{f(g(a+h))-f(g(a))}{g(a+h)-g(a)}\cdot\frac{g(a+h)-g(a)}{h}.$$
If $|h|$ is very small, then $|g(a+h)-g(a)|$ is also very small since $g$ is continuous at $a$.
If $|h|$ is very small and $g(a+h)-g(a)\neq 0$, then $\frac{f(g(a+h))-f(g(a))}{h}$ is very close to $f^{'}(g(a))\cdot g^{'}(a)$ since $f$ is differentiable at $g(a)$ and $g$ is differentiable at $a$.
If $|h|$ is very small and $|g(a+h)-g(a)|=0$, then $\frac{f(g(a+h))-f(g(a))}{h}=0$.
$f^{'}(g(a))\cdot g^{'}(a)\neq 0$ by assumption.
So, $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(g(a+h))-f(g(a))}{h}$ cannot exist.

What is wrong with my above argument?

Comment: |g(a+h)-g(a)|=0 does not imply that (f(g(a+h))-f(g(a))/h=0. The problem is that in your decomposition, you have a 0/0 at some point.

Comment: but since f'(g(a))*g'(a) is not zero, so g'(a) is non zero. Meaning (g(a+h)-g(a))/h tends to non-zero limit g'(a), as h tends to zero. Define a function F(h)=(g(a+h)-g(a))/h, this can be extended continuously to h=0, i.e. let it =g'(a) at h=0. F(0)=g'(a) is not zero. Then by continuity, you can find an interval of  (-epsilon,+epsilon) s.t F(h) is not zero, then you won't have to worry about (g(a+h)-g(a))=0

Comment: @fourofour_un Thank you very much.

Comment: Your argument is correct but why do you make the unnecessary assumption that $f'(g(a)) g'(a) \neq 0$?

Comment: @fourofour_un: $|g(a+h) - g(a) |=0$ _does imply_ that $\frac {f(g(a+h) - f(g(a))} {h} =0$ because numerator is $0$ and denominator $h\neq 0$.